# Create multiple strings based on elseif condition in php

Tags: php, html, string, if-statement, conditional-statements

While this code seems to work to change $tdstyle as anticipated on the td line, it does not update $font and $text appropriately based on the esleif conditions.  It always seems to keep these strings the same based on the else condition alone even if it isn't true.  Maybe just a syntax issue?  I am certain there is a much better way to do this, but my limited knowledge has brought me to this point.  Any suggestions?

```
<?php       
$num = (float)$uvindex;
            if($num >10) {
                $tdstyle='#B567A4';
                $font='white';
                $text='Extreme';
                } elseif($num >=8) {
                $tdstyle='#E53210';
                $font='white';
                $text='Very High';
                } elseif($num >=6) {
                $tdstyle='#F18B00';
                $font='black';
                $text='High';
                } elseif($num >=3) {
                $tdstyle='#FFF300';
                $font='black';
                $text='Moderate';
                } else $tdstyle='#3EA72D'; $font='black'; $text='Low';
            ?>
             <td height="82" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" class="data1" style="text-align:center; background-color:<?php echo $tdstyle ?>; color:<?php echo $font ?>; border: 3px solid black; border-radius: 7px; font-size:12px;">
```

Comment: You would need to put all of the `else` statements in `{}` to keep them together, otherwise the `$font` and `$text` will always be set from there.

Comment: If you look at something like PSR-12 about indentation, it will help in see these sorts of problems purely by the layout of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` is only containing the first statement (where you set `$tdstyle`).

This

```php
// ...
} else $tdstyle='#3EA72D'; $font='black'; $text='Low';
```

is equivalent to

```php
// ...
} else {
    $tdstyle='#3EA72D';
}
$font='black'; // you probably want these in the 
$text='Low';   //  above else block
```

So `$font` and `$text` will always be `'black'` and `'Low'` respectively. Remember that `;` terminates a statement, not a newline. Listen to the comments of Nigel: invest in a formatter to help you catch errors like these.